# How to make the power() function use decimal instead of integer?

Tags: sql-server

The following query throws an error:

```
SELECT POWER( 10, 13)
```

Error message:

```
Msg 232, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 10000000000.000000.
```

Whan can I do to prevent the int overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following

```
SELECT POWER( 10.0, 11 - LEN(9)) - 1
```

**Explanation**

Arithmetic overflow occurs when a calculation produces a result that falls outside the min & max values that a datatype can store. In your case, `POWER( 10, 11 - LEN(9))` produces 10000000000, and the datatype is implicitly implemented as int. This value is greater than the max value that `int` can take, i.e., 2147483647, thus creating the overflow. If you use `POWER( 10.0, 11 - LEN(9))` with 10.0, the calculation produces decimal, as decimal has higher precedence in SQL Server than int. Decimal has a range of `- 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1`, and so does not create overflow for your calculation.

Comment: see my explanation in the post

Answer (score 4):

Add a decimal place:

```
SELECT POWER(10.0, 13)
```

That causes an implicit cast from `int` to `DECIMAL(18,6)`.  You could write it for identical results as:

```
SELECT POWER(CAST(10 as DECIMAL(18,6)), 13)
```

The [`POWER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx) function return type is documented as:

> Returns the same type as submitted in float_expression. For example,
> if a decimal(2,0) is submitted as float_expression, the result
> returned is decimal(2,0)

This means that your result is a `DECIMAL(18,6)`, which in your case is big enough to hold the final result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), 10)
```

This specifies 2 decimal places, but you can modify the numbers within the brackets `(18,5)` to adjust this [precision & scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190476.aspx) as desired